# Android app is not available for tablets

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest

I have seen some answers to this questions, but I can't still make my app appear for tablets on the play store, I hope that you guys can help me, thanks in advance !!
This are the permissions required in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
```

Comment: probably because those tablets dont have SMS capabilities that your permissions require

Comment: I need this permission because in the phone version I send messages, how can I evaluate or change this permission between tablet and phone ?

Comment: then you need to make the permission as not required